# LDAP Server installation issues on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap

I have been trying to install LDAP server on Ubuntu 14 using the instructions at: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html.

According to the url, if i want a suffix of dc=example,dc=com, i should have a line like:

```
127.0.1.1       hostname.example.com    hostname
```

in my /etc/hosts. I have added a line like:

```
127.0.1.1       localhost.example.com   localhost
```

Now, when i install using

```
$ sudo apt-get install slapd ldap-utils
```

It asks for admin password and installation is successful.

But when i run a ldapsearch like:

```
$ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap:/// -b dc=example,dc=com dn
```

it returns me the message:

```
No such object(32)
```

Instead of the following as per the article :

```
dn: dc=example,dc=com

dn: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
```

I am not sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dpkg-reconfigure slapd`. It will run you through a gui asking some parameters.

More information about this process: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1217040&seqNum=5